# RuntimeError: Illegal values for buffer size?

Tags: gdal, buffer, gdal2tiles, runtimeerror

Does anyone know what this "RuntimeError: Illegal values for buffer size" error is? I am running gdal2tiles.py on a geoTIFF. Below is the message in my terminal. I don't know if the buffer size is referring to some gdal parameter or if it's my machine's memory.

```
    gdal2tiles.py --xyz -z 10-18 --zoom=10-18 -a 0 --srcnodata=0 -s EPSG:3857 input/raster/bx-bromley-1911-vol2.tif output/raster/bx-bromley-1911-vol2
Generating Base Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tl3190/anaconda3/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 15, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tl3190/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py", line 4527, in main
    return submain(argv)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tl3190/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py", line 4544, in submain
    single_threaded_tiling(input_file, output_folder, options)
  File "/Users/tl3190/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py", line 4395, in single_threaded_tiling
    create_base_tile(conf, tile_detail)
  File "/Users/tl3190/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py", line 1347, in create_base_tile
    alpha = alphaband.ReadRaster(rx, ry, rxsize, rysize, wxsize, wysize)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tl3190/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 4109, in ReadRaster
    return _gdal.Band_ReadRaster1(self, xoff, yoff, xsize, ysize,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Illegal values for buffer size
make: *** [tile-bx-bromley-1911-vol2] Error 1
```

Comment: I would try to install gdal again. Maybe with some older Python version, the gdal2tiles script is perhaps not tested with Python 3.11.